# How to remove or hide y-axis ticklabels from a matplotlib / seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I made a plot that looks like this

[image]

I want to turn off the ticklabels along the y axis. And to do that I am using

```
plt.tick_params(labelleft=False, left=False)
```

And now the plot looks like this. Even though the labels are turned off the scale `1e67` still remains.
[image]

Turning off the scale `1e67` would make the plot look better. How do I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- `seaborn` is used to draw the plot, but it's just a high-level API for `matplotlib`.

  - The functions called to remove the y-axis labels and ticks are `matplotlib` methods.
- **After creating the plot**, use `.set()`.
- `.set(yticklabels=[])` should remove tick labels.

  - This doesn't work if you use `.set_title()`, but you can use `.set(title='')`
- `.set(ylabel=None)` should remove the axis label.
- `.tick_params(left=False)` will remove the ticks.
- Similarly, for the x-axis: [How to remove or hide x-axis labels from a seaborn / matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476654)
- **Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.2`, `matplotlib 3.6.2`, `seaborn 0.12.1`**

## Example 1

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
exercise = sns.load_dataset('exercise')
pen = sns.load_dataset('penguins')

# create figures
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8, 8))

# plot data
g1 = sns.boxplot(x='time', y='pulse', hue='kind', data=exercise, ax=ax[0])

g2 = sns.boxplot(x='species', y='body_mass_g', hue='sex', data=pen, ax=ax[1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Remove Labels

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8, 8))

g1 = sns.boxplot(x='time', y='pulse', hue='kind', data=exercise, ax=ax[0])

g1.set(yticklabels=[])  # remove the tick labels
g1.set(title='Exercise: Pulse by Time for Exercise Type')  # add a title
g1.set(ylabel=None)  # remove the axis label

g2 = sns.boxplot(x='species', y='body_mass_g', hue='sex', data=pen, ax=ax[1])

g2.set(yticklabels=[])  
g2.set(title='Penguins: Body Mass by Species for Gender')
g2.set(ylabel=None)  # remove the y-axis label
g2.tick_params(left=False)  # remove the ticks

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Example 2

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# sinusoidal sample data
sample_length = range(1, 1+1) # number of columns of frequencies
rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
data = np.array([(np.cos(t*rads)*10**67) + 3*10**67 for t in sample_length])
df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, index=pd.Series(rads.tolist(), name='radians'), columns=[f'freq: {i}x' for i in sample_length])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.plot('radians', 'freq: 1x', data=df)

# or skip the previous two lines and plot df directly
# ax = df.plot(x='radians', y='freq: 1x', figsize=(8, 8), legend=False)
```

[image]

### Remove Labels

```py
# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.plot('radians', 'freq: 1x', data=df)

# or skip the previous two lines and plot df directly
# ax = df.plot(x='radians', y='freq: 1x', figsize=(8, 8), legend=False)

ax.set(yticklabels=[])  # remove the tick labels
ax.tick_params(left=False)  # remove the ticks
```

[image]