# How to remove y-axis tick labels from pandas DataFrame histogram

Tags: pandas

I want to plot a histogram of my DataFrame using `pandas.DataFrame.hist`, but I don't want to show the y-axis tick labels.

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768749/6327658) and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63756670/6327658), but it still doesn't work for `pandas.DataFrame.hist`

So far the code looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'length': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
    'width': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1]
    }, index=['pig', 'rabbit', 'duck', 'chicken', 'horse'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
hist = df.hist(bins=3, ax=ax)
```

And the histogram looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this (edited on mspaint):

[image]

Comment: *Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server* same error happened to me in my answer. So no picture there either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess the correct way to access the AxesSubplot objects would be through the *hist* object, like this. produces the desired output (again upload of figs currently not possible)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'length': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
    'width': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1]
    }, index=['pig', 'rabbit', 'duck', 'chicken', 'horse'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hist = df.hist(bins=3, ax=ax)
hist[0][0].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
hist[0][1].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Very strange, i do not know why your code does not work. However i found a workaround:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'length': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
    'width': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1]
    }, index=['pig', 'rabbit', 'duck', 'chicken', 'horse'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.hist(bins=3, ax=ax, ylabelsize=0) # <- set ylabelsize to zero
```