# Create a subplot without axis but with title and y label

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, subplot

I am trying to create a subplot with the axis kept off but I want to include the labels. Here is my code. I read somewhere that if I do `plt.axis('off')` it would even hide the labels. Is there any workaround this? Here is my code.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 10, figsize=(20,7))
i = 0
for row in range(3):
    for col in range(10):
        if row == 0:
            ax[row][col].imshow(final[i])
            ax[row][col].set_title(temp_df.columns[col])
        
        ax[row][col].tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off', labelleft='on', labelbottom='off')
        ax[row][col].imshow(final[i])
        # ax[row][col].axis('off')
        # ax[row][col].tick_params(axis='both', which='both',length=0)
        if col == 0:
            ax[row][col].set_ylabel(str(cols[row]))
        
        i += 1
```

Snapshot of the subplot generated:
[image]

How can I generate a plot with axis kept off and have the labels in the plot?

Comment: Probable duplicates of [How to remove or hide x-axis labels from a seaborn / matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58476654/7758804) & [How to remove or hide y-axis ticklabels from a matplotlib / seaborn plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63756623/7758804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can remove axis ticks by passing an empty list to `ax.set_xticks` and `ax.set_yticks`:

```
ax[row][col].set_xticks([])
ax[row][col].set_yticks([])
```

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 10, figsize = (20, 7))
for row in range(3):
    for col in range(10):
        if row == 0:
            ax[row][col].set_title('your title')

        ax[row][col].tick_params(top = 'off', bottom = 'off', left = 'off', right = 'off', labelleft = 'on', labelbottom = 'on')
        ax[row][col].imshow(np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 10)))
        ax[row][col].set_xticks([])
        ax[row][col].set_yticks([])
        ax[row][col].set_xlabel('x label')
        if col == 0:
            ax[row][col].set_ylabel(f'row = {row}')

plt.show()
```

[image]