# How to rotate the titles in a FacetGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid, catplot

How can I change the rotation of the titles in each Facet (subplot) of a seaborn figure-level plot.

I would like to rotate label at the top by 90 degrees, and remove label at the bottom.

[image: clik here to see picture]

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
df = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

# Draw a pointplot to show pulse as a function of three categorical factors
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet",
                capsize=.2, palette="YlGnBu_d", height=6, aspect=.75,
                kind="point", data=df)
g.despine(left=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

- In order to change individual features of a seaborn [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) plot, iterate through each axes of the [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), and apply the appropriate [`matplotlib.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html) methods.

  - Use [`.get_title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_title.html) to get the existing title, and then use `rotation=` in [`.set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html).
- Removing the xlabels comes from [How to remove or hide x-axis labels from a seaborn / matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476779/7758804)
- Rotating xtick labels comes from [How to rotate xticklabels in a seaborn catplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63912211/7758804)
- There wasn't an existing question or answer for rotating the facet titles.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

# Draw a pointplot to show pulse as a function of three categorical factors
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet",
                capsize=.2, palette="YlGnBu_d", height=6, aspect=.75,
                kind="point", data=df)
g.despine(left=True)

# rotate the xtick labels
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)

# flatten the array of axes for easy iteration and usage
axes = g.axes.flat

# rotate the titles by iterating through each axes
for ax in axes:
    # get the current title
    title = ax.get_title()
    # set the title and rotate the text
    ax.set_title(title, rotation=90)
    
# remove the yticks from the right Facet
axes[1].tick_params(left=False)

# remove all the xlabels
g.set(xlabel=None)
```

[image]

---

- For axes-level plots, there's no need to iterate through axes, since there's only one.
- Use `.get_xticklabels` with `.set_xticklabels` to rotate xtick labels.

```py
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

# Draw a pointplot to show pulse as a function of three categorical factors
ax = sns.pointplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet", capsize=.2, palette="YlGnBu_d", data=df)

# remove spines
ax.spines[['left', 'right', 'top']].set_visible(False)

# rotate the xtick labels
ax.set_xticklabels(labels=ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)

# set the title and rotate the text
ax.set_title('Diet: Low/No Fat', rotation=90)

# move the legend
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.5), loc='center right', frameon=False)

# remove the xlabels
ax.set(xlabel=None)
```

[image]